# How to update a button onClick function dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, react-state

I'm developing a application where I have a Bootstrap v4 Modal rendering a form inside it to get the input data so I can show it on a "card".
This part is ok, but the thing is, I want to use the same modal to edit the data previously inserted (I'll click in the card and it will make the modal appear with the card data) and this is where I'm stuck. I've been messing around trying to change it's function but have no success yet.

There is a lot of console.log going on since I'm still learning and constantly outputting where my code is stuck.

Ok, this is the main component:

```
import React from 'react';
import './TaskColumn.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import BtnNewTask from '../BtnNewTask/BtnNewTask';
import ToastTask from '../ToastTask/ToastTask';
import ModalTask from '../ModalTask/ModalTask';

class TaskColumn extends React.Component{
    state = {
        tasks: [],
        novaTarefa : true
    };

    // Função chamada ao clicar em CONFIRMAR ao cadastrar uma nova tarefa
    newTask = () => {

        const form = document.getElementById('formTarefa');
        var formValido = true;

        // Verificando se todos os campos foram preenchidos
        for(var i=0; i < form.elements.length; i++){
            if(form.elements[i].value === '' && form.elements[i].hasAttribute('required')){
                formValido = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(formValido){
            // Cria uma nova tarefa
            var novaTarefa  = {
                'Titulo': `(${document.getElementById('nomeCliente').value}) ${document.getElementById('modelo').value}`,
                'Modelo': document.getElementById('modelo').value,
                'Cliente':document.getElementById('nomeCliente').value,
                'Descricao':document.getElementById('descricao').value,
                'DataPedido': document.getElementById('criacao').value,
                'DataEntrega': document.getElementById('entrega').value,
                'Estado': 0
            }

            // Adiciona a nova tarefa no array de objetos salvos no ESTADO do componente
            var state = this.state.tasks;
            state.push(novaTarefa);

            // Atualiza o ESTADO do componente
            this.setState(
                {
                    tasks: state,
                    novaTarefa: this.state.novaTarefa
                }
            );

            $('#modalNewTask').modal('hide');
        }else{
            // Mostrar mensagem de erro
            $('#erroPreenchimento').addClass('show');
            window.setTimeout(()=>{
                document.getElementById('erroPreenchimento').classList.remove('show');
            }, 2000);
        }
    }

    editTask = () => {
        console.log("Editando a tarefa...");
    }

    updateButton = () => {
        var stateTemporario = this.state;
        stateTemporario.novaTarefa = false;
        // console.log(stateTemporario.novaTarefa);
        this.setState(stateTemporario);
        // console.log(this.state);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="col col-md-4">
                <div className="card">
                    <div className="card-header">
                        {this.props.title}        
                    </div>

                    {/* Se houver alguma tarefa salva irá renderiza-las */}
                    {this.state.tasks.length > 0 &&
                        <div className="card-body">
                            {
                                this.state.tasks.map(
                                    (task, i) => {
                                        return (
                                            <ToastTask task={task} i={i} key={i} onClick={this.updateButton}/>                
                                        );
                                    }
                                )
                            }
                        </div>
                    }

                    {/* Se a coluna recebe o título Disponível, então renderiza o botão para adicionar uma nova tarefa */}
                    {this.props.title === "Disponível" && 
                            <BtnNewTask /> 
                    }
                    <ModalTask newTask={this.newTask} editTask={this.editTask} novaTarefa={this.state.novaTarefa} />
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    };
}

export default TaskColumn;
```

and this is the modal:

```
import React from 'react';
import './ModalTask.css';

class ModalTask extends React.Component {

    state = {
        novaTarefa: true
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        console.warn("ModalTask DidUpdate");
        console.log(this.props.novaTarefa);
        console.log(this.state.novaTarefa);
        // this.setState({novaTarefa: this.props.novaTarefa});
    }

    render (){
        return (
            <div className="modal fade" id="modalNewTask" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalNewTask" aria-hidden="true">     
                <div className="alert alert-warning fade" id="erroPreenchimento" role="alert">
                    Preencha <strong>todos</strong> os campos!
                    <button type="button" className="close" aria-label="Close" onClick={()=>{document.getElementById('erroPreenchimento').classList.remove('show');}}>
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div className="modal-content">

                        <div className="modal-header">
                            <h5 className="modal-title">Nova Tarefa</h5>
                            <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        <div className="modal-body">
                            <div className="container-fluid">
                                <form id="formTarefa">
                                    <div className="form-row">
                                        <div className="col">
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <label htmlFor="nomeCliente">Cliente</label>
                                                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="nomeCliente" placeholder="José Souza" required/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col">
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <label htmlFor="modelo">Modelo do aparelho</label>
                                                <input type="text" className="form-control" id="modelo" placeholder="Lenovo Ideapad 310" required/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <label htmlFor="descricao">Descrição</label>
                                        <textarea className="form-control" id="descricao" rows="5" defaultValue={"Relatório:\n\nObservações:"} required></textarea>
                                        <small className="form-text text-muted">
                                            Sua descrição deve ser precisa para facilitar a manutenção e lembre-se de informar os problemas relatados pelo cliente.
                                        </small>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-row">
                                        <div className="col">
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <label htmlFor="criacao">Data do pedido</label>
                                                <input type="date" id="criacao" style={{'width':'100%'}} required/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col">
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <label htmlFor="entrega">Data de entrega</label>
                                                <input type="date" id="entrega" style={{'width':'100%'}} required/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>

                            {/* Here is where I try to render the proper button */}
                            {this.state.novaTarefa ? (
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" id="botaoConfirmar" onClick={this.props.newTask}>Confirmar {console.warn("Botão Nova tarefa")}</button>
                            ) : (
                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" id="botaoConfirmar" onClick={this.props.editTask}>Confirmar {console.warn("Botão Editar tarefa")}</button>
                            )}

                            </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ModalTask;
```

Comment: Please share some code or a working codesandbox proof-of-concept example

Comment: We need to look at your code, to help you.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to post it and appoint where is each thing